# RTSP getting stream data

Tags: c++, qt, rtsp

I have an IP camera which can give me media-data by RTSP.

I develop an application for getting media-data.

I use C++ and Qt3.

I create socket. connect it to my device IP on port=554.

I do first query

```
SETUP rtsp://192.168.4.160/ufirststream RTSP/1.0\r\n
CSeq: 1\r\n
Transport: RTP/AVP; client_port=554\r\n\r\n
```

And get an answer:

```
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 1
Date: Sat, Mar 24 2012 17:24:59 GMT
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;destination=192.168.4.186;source=192.168.4.160;client_port=0-1;server_port=2000-2001
Session: 413F4DDB
```

I parse it for gettin session value, and do next query:

```
PLAY rtsp://192.168.4.160/ufirststream RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 1
Session: 413F4DDB
```

And server says:

```
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 1
Date: Sat, Mar 24 2012 17:25:02 GMT
Session: 413F4DDB
RTP-Info: url=rtsp://192.168.4.160/ufirststream/track1;seq=6716;rtptime=406936711
```

And how  I can get media-data??? I thought that PLAY-method makes server to give me a stream, but it only gives me an url to rtsp and other info...

I need an binary stream from camera, can you give an advise for my next step??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Transport` header of the `SETUP` request indicates which protocol will be used to send the stream, and the `client_port` the ports on which your client will be listening.

Try opening 2 consecutive UDP ports and pass that range as `client_port=port1-port2` instead of 554. These two ports will be used for the RTP and the RTCP streams (video and control data).

In addition, the RTP port number should be an even number, and the RTCP port the next odd number (See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121430/how-do-you-locate-a-free-udp-port-pair) if you want the port range to be random rather than user selected).

Comment: I must create a server socket binded on port1 which I set up earlier? Or I must create client socket and connect to server using client port1 ??

Comment: @mmmaaak Not a server socket but a `QSocketDevice` of `QSocketDevice::Datagram` type. You don't have to connect to the server, you only have to bind the sockets to free UDP ports.